# Pandas dataframe groupby two columns

Tags: group-by, pandas, dataframe

I have apache access log file in the following format which I have imported to a pandas dataframe using apache log parser.

```
123.231.12.97 - - [10/Jun/2013:06:04:46 -0600] "GET /styles-gadgets.css HTTP/1.0" 200 3036 "http://www.gadgets.lk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0"
```

I want to group this by IP and User Agent. Following is my code.

```
log_list = []

for line in f:
    data = p.parse(line)
    data['%t'] = data['%t'][1:12]+' '+data['%t'][13:21]+' '+data['%t'][22:27]
    log_list.append(data)

df = pandas.DataFrame(log_list)

#-------rename data columns in pandas dataframe
df = df.rename(columns={'%>s': 'Status', '%b':'Bytes Returned', 
                        '%h':'IP', '%l':'Username', '%r': 'Request', '%t': 'Time', '%u': 'Userid', '%{Referer}i': 'Referer', '%{User-Agent}i': 'Agent'})


test = df.groupby(['IP', 'Agent'])
```

Is this method correct? `test = df.groupby(['IP', 'Agent'])` . How could I print this?(Using print test.groups gives a confusing result)

I want to see the result as :

```
IP            Agent
123.231.12.97 Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:21.0) Gecko/20...
100.231.12.97 Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:21.0) Gecko/20...
```

Comment: What are you hoping it to print like? (test is a groupby object, see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html ...)

Comment: @Andy Hayden : I have edited it in the question the way that I want to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find a directly way to know that, maybe you can construct a new DataFrame by:

```
pd.DataFrame(g.groups.keys(), columns=g.keys)
```

If you simply want to know the unique (IP, Agent) pair, you can try:

```
df[['IP', 'Agent']].drop_duplicates()
```

Comment: Is this fine if I want to get data between 06.00 and 06.05?.... fd = pd.DataFrame(df(['IP', 'Agent']).between_time('06:00:00', '06:05:00'))

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you've done is close, though I'm not sure the `drop_duplicates` method is doing what you want. [Here's a blog](http://wesmckinney.com/blog/groupby-fu-improvements-in-grouping-and-aggregating-data-in-pandas/) with more ideas for grouping and querying.

Just iterate through the groups to print them:

```
for group in df.groupby(['IP', 'Agent']):
    print group
```